# How to start a Python script from Django website?

Tags: python, django, button, hyperlink

I've made a Django website, whence I would like to call a Python program that I currently start from the command line.

I imagine doing it by clicking on a link or button.

I know this must be a one-liner, but I'm stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import yourscript # is in yourscript.py

yourclass = yourscript.Yourclass()
yourclass.run()
```

Or something like that?

Answer (score 3):

[Here is an article from Guido Van Rossum](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=4829), who created python, on doing this. Essentially, you just want to invoke your main() function from your controller.